# Add TableView into .xib View in swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, nib

On clicking button  I have a .xib view in which I define a tableView.Here for cell  I create  another .xib file  because there is only option . no default cell is there I think..  so How can I display the items in tableview cell.
I have registered the  .Xib like this and tried but surprising view I got.

```
class CustomAddOnVC: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

let items = ["pk","ak","sk"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
 func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return items.count
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let identifier = "Cell"
    var cell: CustomOneCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier,forIndexPath: indexPath) as? CustomOneCell
    if cell == nil {
        tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "CustomOneCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier,forIndexPath:indexPath ) as? CustomOneCell
        cell.addOnName.text = items[indexPath.row]
        cell.addOnPrice.text = "£0.0"
    }
    
    return cell
}
```

Here the items counting came as 3 but the data is populating in the first one only.

**screenshot**

[image]

And one more thing How can I set the the height of view till the end of all items??  As you can see extra space after the items. If i decrease the size and more items came then again same problem.I want to set the height dynamically according to the items data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because it does not enter your `cell == nil` anymore as you register for the first time. Therefore, my suggestion is to move your updating text outside the if statement. Like this:

```
if cell == nil {
    tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "CustomOneCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)
    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier,forIndexPath:indexPath ) as? CustomOneCell
}
cell.addOnName.text = items[indexPath.row]
cell.addOnPrice.text = "£0.0"`
```

Comment: but how can I set the view size  according to the items... for example if I have only one data then the size of the view   should be the size of the  table

Comment: If you are using auto layout you will need to update the constraint. Maybe create a new question and show some code that you will try or face difficulties with so it will be clearer.